# Is there a way to repost a facebook post using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have got tokens of some account, IDs of posts and their authors and need to make a script which repost a post on other profiles.
Is it even possible?

Comment: No that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You repost using a page access_token:

First, get infos of post:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/<page_id>/feed?fields=id,message,attachments&access_token=<access_token>
```

If the post is a status, you can repost like by POST to `feed` nomal

If the post is a photo, you can repost by POST to `photos`:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me/photos?url=<attachment_media_source>&caption=<caption>&access_token=<your_page_accesstoken>
```

If the post is a video, you can repost by POST to `videos`:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me/videos?file_url=<attachment_media_source>&caption=<caption>&access_token=<your_page_accesstoken>
```